# Prevent profiler pane from obstructing the view

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

As the profiler pane grows, it starts obstructing the edit area:

[image: fig1]

There doesn't seem to be any way to prevent this save for deleting it from DOM by hand.

The ideas are: make it collapsible, cleanable or semi-transparent.

Personally, I can hide it with an ad blocker, but I wish to rather have it fixed for everyone.

Comment: Transparency doesn't seem a good idea - it will still make it harder to read the code.

Comment: This is only the case for screens sizes below 1024px, right?

Comment: My screen is 1024x768. I tried on a larger resolution and found out: the page content is limited to `980px` width, and the profiler pane is `64px` wide. So, it obscures the content if the browser window is less than `1108px` wide since the content is centered.